# NSPersistentContainer is not initialized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nspersistentstore

I added CoreData to an existing project and I cannot get my `NSPersistentContainer` to Initialize.  Here is my code in the App Delegate:

```
var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TimeConverter")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

The app crashes, only when I try to save the managedObjectContext. The error (In the App Delegate) is:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

why is it not being initialized?

```
func saveContext ()
{
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is where it is called in the viewcontroller

```
 func save(event: String,fromCourse:String,toCourse:String,fromTime:String,convertedTime: String)
{
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        else
    {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ConversionHistory",
                                            in: managedContext)!

    let conversion = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: managedContext);

    conversion.setValue(event,          forKeyPath: "event")
    conversion.setValue(fromCourse,     forKeyPath: "fromCourse")
    conversion.setValue(toCourse,       forKeyPath: "toCourse")
    conversion.setValue(fromTime,       forKeyPath: "fromTime")
    conversion.setValue(convertedTime,  forKeyPath: "toTime")




    do
    {
        try managedContext.save()
      //  people.append(person)
    } catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code where you save the context, because this code snippet looks good. Another problem may be that the method loadPersistentStores is asynchronous. It means, you can use container context only after the completionHandler is called.

Comment: When does it crash? The function in the viewcontroller calls the save() method directly on the context - not the saveContext() in your AppDelegate. Besides that, I would second the comment of @AlexanderGaidukov: the persistentContainer is just not ready, when you try to access its context. Make the persistentContainer an optional, set it from the completion handler and check for != nil before accessing the context.

Comment: The app crashes in my ViewController when I try to create an NSEntityDescription in the managedcontext.  The code is:       let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ConversionHistory",
                                                in: managedContext)!

Comment: Are you sure your NSPersistentContainer(name: "TimeConverter") has the same name as your coredata? I tried running your code on sample core data model (test_test.xcdatamodeld). And it worked fine for me. BUT when I altered to NSPersistentContainer(name:"test_test") to NSPersistentContainer(name: "test"). It gave me; thread 1: Signal Sigbart.